# How to find the following limit? $\lim\limits_{x\to 1}(2-x)^{\tan({x\pi}/2)}$

Tags: calculus, limits

Find the limit $$\lim_{x\to 1}(2-x)^{\tan({x\pi}/2)}$$

I'm not sure of the first step, do I take the log? if so can I use L'H rule? I've never come across this yet and I can't find examples online. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Try to apply the $\log $ function and then calcule the value of the limit.

Answer (score 4):

You definitely want to try L'Hospital's rule here. Let's define the following function

$$y(x) = (2-x)^{\tan(\pi x/2)}.$$

Then

$$\log y(x) = \tan(\pi x/2)\log(2-x).$$

As $x\rightarrow 0$, $\tan(\pi x/2)\rightarrow \infty$ (either positive or negative infinity) and $\log(2-x)\rightarrow 0$. Thus $\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}\log y(x)$ is indeterminant. However the right hand side is not quite in the form that we need to apply L'Hospital's Rule since it is geared to work for *quotients* of functions - not products. However we can remedy that easily:

$$\log y(x) = \frac{\log(2-x)}{\cot(\pi x/2)}.$$

Applying L'Hospital's rule gives that

$$ \lim_{x\rightarrow 1} \frac{\log(2-x)}{\cot(\pi x/2)} = \lim_{x\rightarrow 1}\frac{-\frac{1}{2-x}}{-\frac{\pi}{2}\csc^2(\pi x/2)} = \lim_{x\rightarrow 1}\frac{2}{\pi}\frac{\sin^2(\pi x/2)}{2-x}.$$

Now can you take it from here?

Comment: how did you make it so the cot was underneath the log?

Comment: We know that by definition $\cot x = \dfrac{1}{\tan x}$ so $\tan x = \dfrac{1}{\cot x}.$

Comment: that's right. I should be able to.

Comment: I'm getting 2/pi. could you verify that for me?

Comment: could someone answer the question then? I don't know where I am going wrong.

Comment: I'll fill in the details in my post.

Comment: I edited my post. Does this help?

Comment: is that x approaching zero a mistype? the original problem had a x approaching 1

Comment: I fixed the error. The $2/ \pi$ you get is correct for the limit however there is something missing. Notice that we took a logarithm..